# How to create EC2-instance with python with attaching of already created security group

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, boto3

This is my code:

```
image_id='ami-0bbc25e23a7640b9b'
instance_type='t2.micro'
keypair_name='my_key'
security_group_id='my_security_group_id'

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
response = ec2.create_instances(ImageId=image_id,InstanceType=instance_type,KeyName=keypair_name,MinCount=1,MaxCount=1,SecurityGroups=[security_group_id])
```

In output i see

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2.py", line 98, in <module>
    response = ec2.create_instances(ImageId=image_id,InstanceType=instance_type,KeyName=keypair_name,MinCount=1,MaxCount=1,SecurityGroups=[security_group_id])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the RunInstances operation: Value () for parameter groupId is invalid. The value cannot be empty
```

Where i have error ?
I tried to use `boto3.client` with `ec2.run_instances`, but result the same. Can You help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a Security Group ID (eg `sg-93db39f6`), then you should pass it in `SecurityGroupIds` (not `SecurityGroups`).